# What type of Pronominal verb is "acabarse" and when to use it over "acabar" to mean that "something comes to an end"?

Tags: verbo-pronominal

On SpanishDict they have an example of *"acabar"* and *"acabarse"* to indicate something comes to an end, and it is unclear to me what the difference is and when to use the pronominal version:

- *"Te llamaré después de que acabe la película"*: I'll call you after the movie ends.
- *"La película se acabó temprano"*: The movie finished early.

Also, is *"acabarse"* a reflexive pronominal?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that most of the usages given in the DLE whether transitive or intransitive are not also used as pronominal https://dle.rae.es/acabar?m=form The pronominal ones are marked U, t. c. prnl

Answer (score 2):

The sentence:

- La película se acabó temprano.

is not idiomatic. We would normally use non-pronominal "acabar" or "terminar".

"Acabarse" is generally used to mean "run out":

- Las provisiones se acabaron. (The supplies ran out.)

or to mean "come to an (abrupt though expected) end":

- Mis esperanzas se acabaron. (My hopes came to an end.)

Comment: I'm sorry Gustavson, did you mean to make the examples with "acabaron" or "acabarse"?

Comment: As I said, in the examples with "se" the verb is more than just "finish". It's more like "run out".

Comment: Yes, acabarse is run out (El cafe se acabo.).